Use flutter shader to create pixel painting software to improve performance,Experiencing memory problems
I am writing drawing software with flutter, and in order to improve the performance of the software and add features such as brushes, I use shaders to draw. That is, I set the image to the shader before drawing, I have observed that it performs very well after this, and after drawing it uses toImageSync() to convert it into a ui.Image object for rendering to the screen
My current approach:
I currently have a Layer class which contains properties such as blending mode, hiding layers, and most importantly a Uint8List variable which stores the information of layers. Assuming my canvas size is 16 x 16, the information stored in a Uint8List variable is 16 x 16 x 4. There is also a variable of type ui.Image, which is used when blending multiple layers. ui.Image will only be updated if the Unint8List variable is modified. This is my current approach.
//isInvalidated The function of the variable is to mark whether the data of the current layer has been modified. If it has been modified, it is generated by executing ui.decodeImageFromPixels().

//image Image for layer blending

Future<ui.Image?> render(ui.Size canvasSize) async {
    
    if (!isInvalidated) {
      return image;
    }
    isInvalidated = false;

    if (!isCanRender) {
      return null;
    }

    var complater = Completer<ui.Image>();

    ui.decodeImageFromPixels(pixelData, canvasSize.width.toInt(), canvasSize.height.toInt(), ui.PixelFormat.rgba8888, complater.complete);

    image = await complater.future;

    return image;
}




//This is the function used for layer blending
Future<ui.Picture> blendLayers(BuildContext context, Size canvasSize) async {
    ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    ui.Canvas canvas = ui.Canvas(recorder);

    var frameModel = context.read<FrameModel>();

    for (int i = 0; i < frameModel.frameList[frameModel.currentEditFrame].layers.length; i++) {
      if (!frameModel.frameList[frameModel.currentEditFrame].layers[i].visible) {
        continue;
      }

      final image = await frameModel.frameList[frameModel.currentEditFrame].layers[i].render(context.read<ToolParameter>().canvasSize);
      var layerBlendMode = frameModel.frameList[frameModel.currentEditFrame].layers[i].blendMode;

      if (i == 0) {
        layerBlendMode = LayerBlendMode.normal;
      }

      if (image != null) {
        canvas.drawImage(
            image,
            Offset.zero,
            Paint()
              ..color = Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, frameModel.frameList[frameModel.currentEditFrame].layers[i].transparence / 100.0)
              ..blendMode = getBlendMode(layerBlendMode));
      }
    }

    return recorder.endRecording();
}

This method has achieved good performance, but I feel that it is not enough, and I have been trying new things so that I can provide better software to my users, which is also my dream.
I have tried:
I didn't have a lot of experience with shaders before, but to improve performance, I gave them a try, and I have to say that they did have good performance, but after a while there would be memory issues until they crashed.
#version 460 core

#include <flutter/runtime_effect.glsl>

precision mediump float;

//Output color
out vec4 fragColor;

//Center position and radius
uniform vec2 u_center;
uniform float u_radius;

//brush color
uniform vec4 u_color;

//shape type
uniform float u_shape_type;

//The texture is valid if the selected type is Custom
//uniform sampler2D uTexture;

//x-symmetry
uniform float x_axis_symmetry;

//x-symmetry position
//uniform float x_axis_symmetry_position;

//y-symmetry
//uniform float y_axis_symmetry;

//y-symmetry position
//uniform float y_axis_symmetry_position;



void main()
{   
    if(u_shape_type == 0){
        //draw rect
        if(FlutterFragCoord().xy.x > u_center[0] - u_radius && 
            FlutterFragCoord().xy.x < u_center[0] + u_radius && 
            FlutterFragCoord().xy.y > u_center[1] - u_radius && 
            FlutterFragCoord().xy.y < u_center[1] + u_radius)
        {
            fragColor = u_color;
        }else{
            fragColor = vec4(0.0);
        }
    }else if(u_shape_type == 1){
        //Calculate the distance from the current coordinate to the center of the circle
        float dis = distance(FlutterFragCoord().xy, u_center);
        //If the distance is less than the radius, color is drawn, otherwise transparent
        if (dis < u_radius)
        {
            fragColor = u_color;
        }
        else
        {
            fragColor = vec4(0.0);
        }
    }else if(u_shape_type == 2){
        //chartlet
        //fragColor = texture(u_texture, FlutterFragCoord().xy / u_resolution);
    }
}

This is my shader code
ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
ui.Canvas canvas = ui.Canvas(recorder);

//Create a shader and set shader parameters
//code ...

//canvas.draw()...
//code ...

ui.Image image = recorder.endRecording().toImageSync(canvas_width, canvas_height);

Then use image to blend the layers
I expect results :
In my observations, performance did improve, but software memory was not smooth.
What I expect is that the software memory can be smooth, while the performance can be improved
